# Deleting columns containing specific string with csv module

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to write a python program to process csv sheets, the total numbers of rows and cols are different each time.

One of things I want to do is to delete columns containing a specific string.

```
import csv
input = open("1.csv","rb")
reader = csv.reader(input)
output = open("2.csv","wb")
writer = csv.writer(output)
index = -1
for row in reader:
    for item in row:
        if  item == str('string'):
            index = row.index(item)
            print(index)
            ...
```

Update:I rewrite the code thanks to [tuan-huynh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2305843/tuan-huynh/), but this code only works for the first column containing "string".

Comment: To be clear, you're saying if a column contains a given string, you want to delete that *column*, not the *row*(s) with the offending string? The code you've given isn't even syntactically legal, and your naming is wrong (when you iterate a `csv.reader`, you get a row on each loop, not a column), so it's hard to know what you really want. You'll need to figure out whether you mean rows or columns, and provide a [MCVE], with example inputs and expected outputs (and observed outputs if your code runs incorrectly) to make it possible to answer this question.

Comment: As for "how they're indexed", the `csv` module documentation includes several examples to get an idea of how it works, so I'd suggest looking at the example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the column index with this code and can delete it. I test it ok

import csv

```
with open("SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("result","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        index = -1
        for r in rdr:
           for item in r:
               if  item == str(string):
                    index = r.index(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume csv looks like

```
name,color,price
apple,red,10
banana,yellow,5
```

```
import csv
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    file = csv.reader(f)
    for line in file:
        print(line[0], line[1], line[2])
```

print out would be

```
name color price
apple red 10
banana yellow 5
```

Comment: What does this have to do with deleting columns?

Comment: **Then I want it to return the column number so I can exclude it later when reconstructing the csv column by column.** Once you get the index of column, the rest is pretty obvious.

Comment: Feel free to edit your post to add extra information